# JMeter Compare JSON with JDBC Request

Tags: json

I have a JSON like below:
{
"abc":" hello",
"def":" hi"
}
I want to compare thus with JDBC request output. I have saved the output in variables "abc" and "def" so as to match my JSON. I am using groovy to compare. I tried using JsonSlurper but could not retrieve the elements in JSON by index so that I can iterate through the JSON response. Please help me on this.